# Transition from in-house to agency position–How to measure UX success

Tags: measuring, metrics

I've recently made the move from in-house UX designer to working at an agency. While working in house, a big part of my job was defining success metrics, measuring for success, and iterating. Most of the work we get through the agency is very interesting enterprise application design, but we are almost always asked to come on-board, work on a project for a couple of months, then hand it off. There is no plan to engage the client in the long-term, we just design a ship and wish them luck.

It seems to me that we (us and the client) are missing crucial steps in the process; the ongoing analysis, testing, and iteration. Does anybody have any experience with building these steps into the design process from an agency perspective? Sharing your experience pointing to any relevant resources would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If the agency is not willing to invest in those steps, no matter what ideas or efforts you put into building them, they'd remained discarded and you'd be accused of wasting time while being paid for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my last job at an agency we started to do some of this work. It involved baking in measurable goals early in the project much like you would if you were working in-house.

1. Write your problem statement, your hypothesis and what success looks like.
2. Determine what KPI's could measure success.
3. Help your client get set up to measure those KPI's - for example, if they do not have GA instrumentation set up, help them get it set up. If they do not have A/B testing capabilities, help them get set up with those.
4. If they will, have them give you continued access to their analytics so you can help guide with A/B testing or iterative work.